# Firebase invites links through mail giving 404 error

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-invites

I have firebase invites in my app. I send invites through mail and messages for both ios and android plateforms. When i send it through messages, it works fine in both the devices, it opens app in play store in android and app in app store in iphone. But when i send the invitations through mail, on clicking on the install link, it gives 404 error.

[link description here](https://plus.google.com/appinvite/cliend_id)

This is the link i get when i open it in android or iphone.

This is the code i am using to invite.

```
// Invite friends
id<FIRInviteBuilder> inviteDialog = [FIRInvites inviteDialog];
[inviteDialog setInviteDelegate:self];


FIRInvitesTargetApplication *targetApplication = [[FIRInvitesTargetApplication alloc] init];
targetApplication.androidClientID = @"android_client_id";
[inviteDialog setOtherPlatformsTargetApplication:targetApplication];    
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:SHARE_MESSAGE];

[inviteDialog setMessage:message];

[inviteDialog setTitle:@"Invite Friends"];

[inviteDialog open];
```

Please help me with this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to specify the appStoreID in the firebase console of my project to get rid of this issue. If your app isn't there in the app store then you can use the dummy for testing purpose, i have used id284882215 of facebook.

Answer (score 2):

I got that 404 too and found that I had to specify a deep link. It doesn't seem to matter what the link is, though I'm using my website. Without the deep link this seems to fall back to appinvite, the older SDK. With it it uses the Firebase Invite SDK.

Comment: Thank you! Weird how this is the solution, and how it is unclear in the documentation. This should be accepted answer.